Why used printf the same variable addr twice result in different print values?
Environnment:

gcc version 9.4.0 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2))

The conditions under which this occurs are:

The printed variable is of float type.
There are type conversion errors in the printf.
The buffer is refreshed before the printf call.

Build command:
gcc floatTest.c -o floatTest -std=c99(arg c17 c11 c99 the result same as)

Code (also available on Godbolt):
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float test = 5.0;
    printf("first print   test data is %x test %p\n", test, &test);
     //fflush(stdout);
    printf("second print  test data is %x test %p\n", test, &test);
}

Output:
first print   test data is 37df33f4 test 0x7ffd37df3508
second print  test data is 37df33f4 test (nil)

I tried printing an integer type, and none of the mentioned issues occurred. The problem only arises when printing a floating-point type, and when the three conditions mentioned above are met, abnormal values are printed. I also tried using different compiler versions, but the results were consistently abnormal. Switching between different C standards yielded the same result. However, note that when I compiled and tested using Visual Studio 2022, the issue did not occur.

"There are type conversion errors in the printf." Oops!  So you cross the street without looking out for traffic, and are only sometimes run over by a bus?

Hi. To be clear, and I feel it is not clear in the answer below, it is that the presented code is incorrect. Any compiler can do anything with such code, as the presented code itself is invalid and contains an error. You can't expect any sane output from such code from any compiler. That you can get any output from any compiler, and they differ anyhow, it is just a whim of the universe, it just "happens", none of the compiler writers care about it, it is not a bug anywhere in the compiler or environment. It is a bug in the code itself.

Yes, type conversion errors are not allowed. I am just puzzled as to why a type conversion error would cause the pointer to print as nil, and why this issue does not occur if the buffer is not flushed.

@AlanBai undefined behavior is undefined. Basically anything can happen. When printf "sees" %x it expects an int, but you provide a float (actually rather a double because floats are implicitly converted to double in variadic parameter lists) you get undefined behavior.

@Alan - To explain the unexplainable - like hinted at in the answers - the compiler passes arguments by placing them at locations the receiving function expects. Different type of arguments can be passed in different ways, or using different locations. Calling another function in-between can affect the location where the argument should have been, had it been of the right type and size...


Why used printf the same variable addr twice result in different print values?

From X86-64 ABI (that I guess that you are using) https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/elf/x86_64-abi-0.99.pdf section 3.2.3 Parameter passing we know that:

arguments of type float and double is in SSE class
arguments of pointer type are in INTEGER class
arguments of int type, that %x expects, are also in INTEGER class

Pointer types and int types use the same class. From page 20 of the document the class INTEGER types use the next available register of the sequence %rdi, %rsi, %rdx, %rcx, %r8 and %r9 is used and SSE class use different registers.
        movss   xmm0, dword ptr [rbp - 4]
        cvtss2sd        xmm0, xmm0
        lea     rdi, [rip + .L.str.2]
        lea     rsi, [rbp - 4]
        /* note - rdx not assigned */
        mov     al, 1
        call    printf@PLT

The format string passed to printf is a pointer. When printf starts, it reads the format string from %rdi register that points to the format string.
Then to output the %x printf reads the content of the next register in INTEGER class %rsi and prints it formatted as an hex. The content of this register is populated with the next argument in INTEGER class, so the first printed value 37df33f4 is actually the address of &test reinterpreted as an int. You can confirm this by adding for example printf("%x\n", (int)(void*)&test); to your code.
Then the %p format specifier makes printf read a value from the next INTEGER class register %rdx. That register is not touched before the call to printf, so %rdx contains any garbage value that was there before the call to printf.
On the beginning of your program, the %rdx register happens to contain the value 0x7ffd37df3508. That value most probably comes from the 3rd argument to main. On POSIX systems, the C standard library calls the main with 3 arguments main(argv, argc, environ), and all these arguments happen to be in INTEGER class. The address to environ is placed in the %rdx register, and your main code does not override it, so the first printf call happens to print it. You can confirm it by printing extern char **environ; printf("%p\n", (void*)environ); and comparing the result.
After the call to printf, the %rdx register happens to contain the value 0. That value is assigned somewhere inside printf source code. You would have to go with a disassembler to get the exact location where it is assigned.
Note that this answer is solely very specific to X86-64 ABI. Also the compiler can detect that the code is invalid and decide to spawn nasal demons instead of producing any sane output.
#include <stdio.h>
extern char **environ;
int main() {
    float test = 5.0;
    printf("first print   test data is %x test %p\n", test, (void*)&test);
    printf("second print  test data is %x test %p\n", test, (void*)&test);
    printf("&test = %x\n", (int)(void*)&test);
    printf("environ = %p\n", (void*)environ);
}

first print   test data is 978a72ec test 0x7ffd978a7418
second print  test data is 978a72ec test (nil)
&test = 978a72ec
environ = 0x7ffd978a7418


why this issue does not occur if the buffer is not flushed

Because fflush happens to assign some different value to %rdx register. You would have to go through a disassembler or debugger to find the location where this register happens to be assigned.

%x is used to print float in hexadecimal format, not for printing addr.

@AlanBai you can't do that. Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior, and undefined behavior means anything can happen. Who said that printf will get the correct value of the float and convert to hex. The float can't even be passed into printf because they'll all undergo default promotion in variadic functions so printf only sees a double

@Alan Bai If you want to see what a float looks like when printed as, say an unsigned int or a uint32_t (or whatever is the same size as a float), then use a union. Set the float in the union and pass the unsigned integer in the union to printf. Then the function arguments will use the correct registers.

The arguments seems to be missing from your main() line and environ is currently used before declaration.

hi @AlanBai %x is used to print float in hexadecimal format, not for printing addr %x is to print an int, it can never print a float. On your machine, %x is used to print whatever the value is in the next INTEGER class register. Float is stored in xmm0 register, %x does not touch that. You can learn more about registers from like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_register https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086 and all other wiki pages. There are also millions of good books about computer architecture.

Yes, your example snippet is less confusing and good enough now. Maybe you can consider declaring it char** to match the usual usage although it doesn't really matter in this case.

There is no particular reason why two identical, consecutive function calls with the same undefined behavior (function call argument types do not match the expected function parameter types after default argument promotions for variadic arguments of printf) should produce the same results.
For example, in some ABI (application binary interface) definitions, some function call arguments are passed in registers, with floating point arguments passed to the called function in completely different registers than integer arguments, so the printf call will be printing a junk register value.
One way to print a float in hexadecimal as though it was an integer, is to use a union type containing a float member and an unsigned integer type of the same size as the float. Let us assume that uint32_t is the same size as a float, then:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main()
{
    union
    {
        float f;
        uint32_t u32;
    } test;
    test.f = 5.0;
    printf("first print   test data is %08"PRIx32" test %p\n", test.u32, (void *)&test);
     //fflush(stdout);
    printf("second print  test data is %08"PRIx32" test %p\n", test.u32, (void *)&test);
}

Example output:
first print   test data is 40a00000 test 0x7ffec4f1683c
second print  test data is 40a00000 test 0x7ffec4f1683c


But why is the “floating-point register” being destroyed? How is this related to the incorrect type conversion in printf?

@AlanBai your arguments are a floating point value and a pointer, your formatting says you have an integer and a pointer. Assuming that pointers and integers are passed similarly, it prints the pointer as an hex integer then whatever junk is the next integer ABI argument as a pointer.

The key point is that if fflush(stdout) is used and the original first printf is removed, the result of printing the test pointer is still null. It's not that the second print is using an undefined junk register value after the first print.

@AlanBai The floating point register probably isn't being destroyed. printf is probably expecting the first integer register to contain the %x value and the second integer register to contain the %p value (pointer arguments and integer arguments use the same set of registers in some ABIs). But the call set the first float register to test and the first integer register to &test, with nothing in the second integer register.
